# How to resolve sp.TKey is not sp.TAddress error in SmartPy?

Tags: node, smart-contracts, smartpy

I have a function like this

```
@sp.entry_point
    def _verifySigPersonalSign(self,req,sig):
        
        sp.verify((req.deadline != sp.timestamp(0)) | (sp.now<=req.deadline), "request expired")
        digest = sp.sha256(sp.pack(sp.record(sender=req.sender,to=req.to,token=req.token,txGas=req.txGas,tokenGasPrice=req.tokenGasPrice,batchId=req.batchId,nonce=self.data.nonces[req.sender][req.batchId],deadline=req.deadline,data=sp.sha256(req.data))));
        signer=req.sender
        sp.verify(sp.check_signature(req.sender,sig,digest))
```

and created a test for it :

```
req = sp.TRecord(sender=alice.public_key,to=bob.public_key,token=sp.address("tz1YtuZ4vhzzn7ssCt93Put8U9UJDdvCXci4"),txGas=1,tokenGasPrice=2,batchId=1,batchNonce=2,deadline=sp.timestamp(1),bytes=sp.pack('42'))
        AliceSignature=sp.make_signature(secret_key=alice.secret_key,message=req,message_format="Raw")
        secanrio += c1._verifySigPersonalSign(req,AliceSignature)
```

But I am receiving an error:

```
Error: Type Error
sp.TKey is not sp.TAddress
sp.check_signature (params.req.sender : sp.TAddress)
```

on the line last line of the code : `sp.verify(sp.check_signature(req.sender,sig,digest))`.
I need this line in my contract and also tried some debugging and found if I comment out this line then I receive another error:

```
Error: : Cannot read property '$nat' of undefined

Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Can someone please help me resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example with the correct syntax, I hope this helps.
[Contract Link](https://smartpy.io/ide?cid=QmNoQRaQMHJ9njbTAscf7uSB7WfDYCtRaA8Cc9osYHd66B&k=e90991bd5fd9f911cbcb)

The first issue you are having is with the way you call the entrypoint.

It should be `c1._verifySigPersonalSign(req = req, sig = AliceSignature)` instead of `c1._verifySigPersonalSign(req,AliceSignature)`

The second issue is because you are trying to create a record from a type definition:

It should be `sp.record(...)` instead of `sp.TRecord(...)`

Comment: Sorry rodrigo, the second issue gets solved but the first one still occurs with the same message

Comment: Take a close look at the link I posted in the answer above. (It contains a working example of what you are trying to achieve)